# Windows 11 Can't Find NAS

Tags: networking, hard-drive, windows-11, nas

I have a NAS at home - built with a Raspberry Pi and a spare 2TB HDD using the openmediavault package.

Until today I could see it fine as a network drive on my home network using my Windows 11 PC (which I set up to map it to drive letter Z:). Today this broke - I can't access the drive in File Explorer - I get an error code 0x80070035.

I can still find the NAS fine using my iPad, and also on my PC I have a web interface for it which is working fine.

If I go to command prompt and type "NET USE" I see the following:

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disconnected Z:        \\RASPBERRYPI\PiShare     Microsoft Windows Network
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this please?

Edit (to respond to initial comments):

Network discovery is enabled (wired connection to router - PC doesn't have wi-fi)

If I type `ping RASPBERRYPI` at the command prompt I get:

```
Ping request could not find host RASPBERRYPI. Please check the name and try again.
```

If I type `nslookup RASPBERRYPI` I get:

```
C:\Windows\System32>nslookup RASPBERRYPI
Server:  dsldevice.lan
Address:  192.168.1.254

Name:    RASPBERRYPI.lan
Addresses:  192.168.1.123
          192.168.1.123
```

Does that help?

Comment: Can you ping RASPBERRYPI? What does nslookup show for RASPBERRYPI?

Comment: Make sure Network Discovery has not been disabled, or if wireless, not set to Public.

Comment: Thank you both. Have edited my post to include my attempts to follow your guidance - see above

Comment: . Is the Raspberry Pi indeed still at the IP 192.168.1.123 (seen in the `nslookup`)?

Comment: Can you reboot both your router and computer? Alternative things to run in Windows `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear the dns cache in windows `netsh interface IP delete arpcache` to clear the arp cache (unlikely to be an issue, but worth a last ditch). There are other things to reset in Windows networking but if rebooting and resetting those don't work then you likely have a deeper problem.

Comment: Error 0x80070035 means "The Network Path was Not Found". The RP dropped out of the network. Does it help to reboot it?

Comment: @harrymc how can the RP be dropped out of the network if it's accessible on the iPad and in a browser?

Comment: @YisroelTech I can see "raspberrypi b8:27:eb:a4:61:4a 192.168.1.123" in my router admin browser thingy so the IP address seems to be correct.

Comment: A firewall that blocks the RP will also give the impression that it dropped out.

Comment: IT'S FIXED!! I did the `ipconfig /flushdns` and the `netsh interface IP delete arpcache` and the router reboot and the PC reboot - and everything is working now (and the `ping` command works too. A thousand thank yous for all the replies. I'm not sure which bit of this is responsible for making it working again but I'm going to pin this page and keep it, lest the problem recur.

Comment: @Alan Feel free to post an answer with the steps taken. Likely one of the commands or reboots flushed some cache where *something* changed and your computer didn't get a new address. Maybe your computer had an old IP address for the RPi cached somewhere, or your router DNS cache glitched out so your computer *couldn't* get a new address for the RPi when it tried but your iPad had the address cached still. Sometimes "reboot everything" is the best solution.

Comment: @Mokubai thank you - yes, will post an answer below shortly (probably tomorrow but it’s on my to do list )

Comment: Also, it's generally considered a good practice to not have dynamic IP addresses on file servers, so if possible assign your raspi the same IP address. If you use DHCP most routers have an option to always assign the same IP to the device.

Comment: Update 2 weeks on: the problem keeps occurring. The fix always works though. In fact, just restarting my router seems to fix it without the other steps. I wonder if my router is somehow faulty...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing the following (as advised in the comments):

- Open Command Prompt
- Execute `ipconfig /flushdns` at command line
- Execute `netsh interface IP delete arpcache` at command line
- Reboot PC and router

The drive reappeared on my network in Windows File Explorer. The mapping to drive letter `Z:` had disappeared, but this is very easy to recreate.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the accepted answer then :-)

Comment: Will do (system says it won't let me do this until tomorrow)

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue of your Windows 11 PC not being able to find your NAS (Raspberry Pi) on the network, you can try the following steps:

1. Check Network Connection: Ensure that both your Windows 11 PC and
   Raspberry Pi NAS are connected to the same network (the same
   router). Verify that your PC has a stable network connection.
2. Verify NAS Accessibility: Since you mentioned that you can access
   the NAS using your iPad and the web interface on your PC, it
   suggests that the NAS is functioning correctly. However,
   double-check the NAS's IP address and hostname to ensure they
   haven't changed.
3. Disable Firewall/Antivirus: Temporarily disable any third-party
   firewall or antivirus software on your Windows 11 PC to see if they
   are causing any interference. If you can access the NAS after
   disabling them, you may need to adjust the firewall or antivirus
   settings to allow network access to the NAS.
4. Check Network Discovery Settings: Confirm that network discovery is
   enabled on your Windows 11 PC. Here's how to check:
   ---- Go to "Settings" by clicking on the Start button and selecting the
   gear icon.
   ---- Click on "Network & Internet." In the left sidebar, select "Ethernet" or "Wi-Fi," depending on your connection.
   ---- Scroll down and    click on "Network and Sharing Center."
   ---- In the Network and Sharing    Center, click on "Change advanced sharing
   settings" on the left.
   ---- Ensure that the following options are
   enabled:
   ---- ---- Turn on network discovery
   ---- ---- Turn on file and printer sharing
5. Flush DNS Cache:    Sometimes, DNS cache issues can prevent
   proper name resolution. To    clear the DNS cache, follow these
   steps:
   ---- Open the Command Prompt as an administrator. Right-click on the Start button and choose "Command Prompt (Admin)."
   ---- Type the following command and press Enter: ipconfig /flushdns
   ---- Wait for the command to execute, and then restart your PC.
6. Check Hostname Resolution: Since you mentioned that you can access
   the NAS using the IP address, but not the hostname, there may be a
   hostname resolution issue on your Windows PC. To troubleshoot this:
   ---- Open the Command Prompt.
   ---- Type the following command and press Enter: ***notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts***
   ---- In the Notepad window that opens, check if there is an entry for your Raspberry Pi NAS. If not, you can manually add an entry in the following format:
     **RASPBERRYPI**
   ---- Save the file and close Notepad.
7. Restart Devices: Restart both your Windows 11 PC and your Raspberry
   Pi NAS. Sometimes a simple restart can resolve temporary network
   issues.

After trying these steps, check if you can access the NAS from your Windows 11 PC. If the problem persists, please provide any additional error messages or details you encounter, as they may help further diagnose the issue.

Comment: thank you - this is all useful info for me (I'm not an expert in this stuff)

Comment: This reads a lot like a list of nearly generic steps that ChatGPT would spit out. Please bear in mind that [ChatGPT is banned here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14862/use-of-chatgpt-is-now-banned-on-super-user)